# Имитация ввода текста в input JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно сделать имитацию ввода текста в placeholder,
Вот так получаю undifined

```
function setText(elem, text, speed) {
  var e = document.querySelector(elem);

  var i = 0,
      int = setInterval(function() {
        if(i == text.length){
          clearInterval(int);
         e.text = 0;
        };
        e.value = e.setAttribute('placeholder', text); // Текст от начала до текущей позиции
        i++;
      }, speed);

  e.focus();
  e.onblur = function() { clearInterval(int) };
};

  setText('#search_input', 'Введите запрос для поиска', 300);
```

Comment: не могли бы Вы прокомментировать вот этот код `e.value = e.setAttribute('placeholder', text);` [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) изменяет атрибут элемента он ничего не возвращает

Answer (score 1):

Вот вроде-бы то,

```js
function setText(elem, text, speed) {
    const e = document.querySelector(elem);

    let i = 0;
    let int = setInterval(function () {
        if (i === text.length - 1) {
            clearInterval(int);
            e.text = 0;
        }
        e.setAttribute('placeholder', text); // Текст от начала до текущей позиции
        e.value += text[i];
        i++;
    }, speed);

    e.focus();
    e.onblur = function () {
        clearInterval(int)
    };
};

setText('#search_input', 'Введите запрос для поиска', 300);
```